# Output to a table, but with different columns

Tags: powershell

I know how to do this in excel, but Im having a difficult time formatting data into a table.

Objective: There are 28 files in a directory. I want files beginning with a certain letter to be in one column, the rest in another. I have the following code:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -File C:\temp\Ins |
         Select Name |
         ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>Folder Contents</h2>' |
         Out-File c:\temp\TableHTML.html
Invoke-Item c:\temp\TableHTML.html
```

So in theory, its fine, as I get a list. I know, then, I have to add the condition

```
Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^[QL]"}
```

As Im wanting to separate files that start with QL in a separate column, however, Im not sure how to incorporate this. When I run, I get all files in one column:

```
290015152S_MstrPolPg.pdf 290015160S_MstrPolPg.pdf 290015169S_MstrPolPg.pdf QLC_NoticeConcernCoverage_590019517SHHJ8RF.PDF QLC_NoticeInfoPractices_290015152SHHJ8SY.PDF QLC_NoticeInfoPractices_290015160SHHJ8UJ.PDF QLC_NoticeInfoPractices_290015169SHHJ8W3.PDF
```

When I want something like this instead:

```
290015152S_MstrPolPg.pdf        QLC_NoticeConcernCoverage_590019517SHHJ8RF.PDF
290015169S_MstrPolPg.pdf        QLC_NoticeInfoPractices_290015160SHHJ8UJ.PDF
```

And so on, in a table with borders, etc. Not comma deliminated.

I just need a nudge in the right direction, can anyone tell me how I use the conditional statement so that it puts files in their respective columns?

Comment: PowerShell doesn't really like the format you're going for. To get that kind of output you need to collect your filenames in a hashtable by `$_.Name -like 'ql*'`, then transpose the hashtable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean that Powershell doesnt like the format, we use powershell to use it all the time using New-Object system.Data.DataTable.  Got a guy in the office and he helped me write it.  However, this is no where near a duplicate, as I needed the info in a table format with borders viewable in email, not in a CSV hashtable comma deliminated.

Ill post the script here so it can help others.

Comment: Your original question (before you changed it completely) was about transforming a list of filenames into a 2-column tabular format. That is essentially a duplicate of the linked question. Questions about formatting `ConvertTo-Html` output have also been asked (and answered) before.

Comment: Thanks, Ansgar.  I needed, as I asked originally and didnt change it completely, "that I did not want a deliminated table, I wanted one with  formatted table with borders."  When I plugged in those keywords, I got essentially what you gave me.... which was a table with no format and delinimated.   However, I didnt know the code ConvertTo-HTML ,so didnt know to look for that.  You can delete this post so it doesnt take up space since its a dupe.  Thanks!! I see the posts you are talking about!  This site is so awesome.